# When placing the legend at "topleft", the characters appear, but the colors do not, what is a solution?

Tags: r, bar-chart, visualization, legend

I have created stand alone code that should illuminate the problem that I am having. I have looked at a number of similar questions on here, but I have had difficulty finding a solution that will work for my situation.

Here is example code:

```
false_matrix <- matrix(nrow =5,ncol=1)
false_matrix[,1]<-c(5,10,15,20,25)
rownames(false_matrix)<-c(2006,2007,2008,2009,2010)
barplot(false_matrix, col = c(terrain.colors(5)),
        beside=TRUE,legend=c(rownames(false_matrix))) 

legend("topleft",col=c(terrain.colors(5)),legend=c(rownames(false_matrix)))
```

That graph has two legends, one from legend = , and one from legend(). Ideally, the legend from the first call would be placed where the second one is. I cannot figure out why the colors are not showing up when i move the legend to "topleft"

The solution should avoid using locator(), because it is going to be used in a Shiny app.

Comment: Try using `fill=` instead of `col=`. I think that will do it.

Comment: Wow, very simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Thanks to @lmo.
fill is the argument that places color within the legend.

```
false_matrix <- matrix(nrow =5,ncol=1)
false_matrix[,1]<-c(5,10,15,20,25)
rownames(false_matrix)<-c(2006,2007,2008,2009,2010)
barplot(false_matrix, col = c(terrain.colors(5)),
        beside=TRUE)
legend("topleft",fill=c(terrain.colors(5)), 
           legend = c(rownames(false_matrix)))
```